# Check to see if date is today or tomorrow

Tags: android

Is it possible to have a check to get today's date and tomorrow's date? For example. If so can someone please help.

```
int cnt = 0;
if( date = today ) 
{
 cnt = 1;
}
else if ( date = tomorrow ) 
{
 cnt = 2;
}
```

Comment: yes it is possible , enough

Comment: @Saurabhsharma how would this be achievable?

Comment: get current date and verify by your date , if it is equal then it is today ....and if the date is incremental by the current date then it is tomorrow , the logic is very simple implement it by your self